# I want to upload file to specific folder with google drive API curl

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, php-curl, google-drive-shared-drive

I have uploaded file to google drive with curl API. But I want to upload file to specific folder. I have also tried with folder id in API url like: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/folder_id?uploadType=media

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_application_form');

function save_application_form($WPCF7_ContactForm) {

    $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm :: get_current();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission :: get_instance();
    if ($WPCF7_ContactForm->id == 8578) {
        if ($submission) {
            $submited = array();
            //$submited['title'] = $wpcf7->title();
            $submited['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();
            $uploaded_files = $submission->uploaded_files();
            $name = $submited['posted_data']["Name"];
            $position_test = $submited['posted_data']["Position"];
            $email = $submited['posted_data']["Email"];
            $phone = $submited['posted_data']["phone"];
            $message = $submited['posted_data']["Message"];
            $position = $submited['posted_data']["AttachYourCV"];

           // $test2 = $_FILES['AttachYourCV']['name'];

            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $cf7_file_field_name = 'AttachYourCV';

            $image_location = $uploaded_files[$cf7_file_field_name];
            $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $image_location);
            $token = GetRefreshedAccessToken('client_id', 'refresh_token', 'client_secret');
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Content-Type:' . $mime_type, // todo: runtime detection?
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
                ),
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents($image_location),
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            $id = json_decode($response, TRUE);
            $get_id = $id['id'];

    curl_close($ch);
   if (isset($id['id'])) {
            $get_id = $id['id'];
            $post_fields = array();
            $folder_id = '1-9r8oVsAfV_iJmYh1cZYPMvE9Qhv8RLA';
            // remove extension  
            $this_file_name = explode('.', $position);

            // submit name field  
            $post_fields['name'] .= $this_file_name[0];
            $post_fields['parents'] = $folder_id[1];
            $ch2 = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch2, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' . $get_id,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Content-Type:application/json', // todo: runtime detection?
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
                ),
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post_fields),
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($ch2);
            if ($response === false) {
                $output = 'ERROR: ' . curl_error($ch2);
            } else {
                $output = $response;
            }

            // close second request handler  
            curl_close($ch2);


        }
}
```

I have added another curl call but still didn't get file in folder. My file untitled issue solved with this way.

Comment: Didn't work with this URL: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/folder_id?uploadType=media

Comment: please include the code you are using for create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading files to google drive is a two part thing. (note it can be done as a single call but if you want to add the corect data its best to do it as two)

[create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) Adds the initial meta data for the file. Name, media type, and location that being its parent directory.

Second the actual upload of the file itself.

*Note: a file uploaded without first sending the metadata will create a dummy metadata most often with a title of the file being "unknown."*

**Create**

When you do your [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) of the inertial metadata. You need to add the parents in this inital call the field is called `parents[]` you need to add the file id there.   I cant help you do this as your not adding the code for it.

**Upload**

By default the file is uploaded into the root folder unless you add a parent folder id for the file.

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) you will find the optional query parms

[image]

Try using `&addParents=[folderId]`

Example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media&addParents=1bpHmln41UI-CRe5idKvxrkIpGKh57T32
```

If you originally created the metadata for the file in the root directory and then try to upload the file to a different directory i suspect that the upload will create new metadata.  These two calls need to be done the same.  Your create should have parents set.

**post body**

```
$data = array("name" => "test.jpg", "parents" => array("123456"));                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
```

Comment: Where can I add? In API url?

Comment: Like this https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media&addParents=[1bpHmln41UI-CRe5idKvxrkIpGKh57T32]

Comment: Remove the []'s You should have created the file with the parent.  I am not sure that uploading a file to a different directly then the metadata was originally created in will work.  Its probably going to create you some dummy metadata for the new upload in the directory.

Comment: Is there any way to do with curl?

Comment: Yes of course do the create with the parent then upload the file to the created metadata.

Comment: I actually don't know where to enter meta data in curl request.
Can you modify my code?

Comment: You said you are calling the create method please post that code as i have already requested.

Comment: I have added the code. This is my final code. I have created folder manually in google drive. Not by code

Comment: I need to see the code where you call https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create  Its in that that you need to add the parent id.

Comment: Not using this type of url
only using https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media to upload file

Comment: Can you plz check my code? I have edit it and add folder id there

Comment: Post body is json. YOu need to create a object to post and then json_encode it

Comment: Still outside the folder. Don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' . $file_id . '?addParents=folder_id&removeParents=root

It is working for me(Not include upload in Request API)

Comment: Most of them facing this issue is because they are sending the addParents in Request Body instead of sending this as query parameters. Your comment was spot on!

Comment: theres no such things as addParents or removeParents where did you get that from?