# Cant upload to subfolder on Google Drive with Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest

I have a successful working version of my code that lets a user choose a file and upload to my Google Drive.
I am using a method that uploads the file in chunks as a resumable upload to get around the 50mb limit. And its great! But it will only upload to the Root folder of my Google Drive!

I have been trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000012/i-want-to-upload-file-to-specific-folder-with-google-drive-api-curl) solution but the accepted answer is only a guess (admitted by the person who answered) and the Comments from the original poster that say what they did to get it working doesnt work for me either.

I have it currently as this for initialising the file to upload:

```
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&addParents=1XVNmZ7Q4vHLB7p9tTk0_rz7Z1VOwy_I8&removeParents=root");
```

This does not give an error, but just puts the file in the Root anyway.

I also tried changing the PUT request for the "resuming" but It either errors out with "file not found" if I dont match the original POST or if I do make them the same, It still just uploads to root!

The Google [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) says what Im doing should work. what am I missing?

Full code here if it helps:

html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    
    <title>Upload Files</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
  
 
 <div class="card py-2 px-5" style="width:550px">
  
   <div class="card-head my-4 border-bottom border-top">
    <h4 class="card-title">Upload File</h4>
   </div></center>
  
  <div class="card-body" id="resp">
   <form id="fileuploadForm">
   
     <li class="list-group-item"><input type="file" name="myFile" id="uploadfile"></li>
   
  </form>
  </div>
        <center><div id="progress" class="display-4"></div></center>

 </div>
 



  
 </div>

<script>
    const chunkSize = 5242880;

    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (file.name != "") {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
            fr.onload = init;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    });

    function init() {
        $("#progress").text("Initializing.");
        var fileName = this.fileName;
        var fileSize = this.fileSize;
        var fileType = this.fileType;
        console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
        var buf = this.result;
        var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
        var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
                data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
                length: e.numByte,
                range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
        });
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(at) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&addParents=1XVNmZ7Q4vHLB7p9tTk0_rz7Z1VOwy_I8&removeParents=root");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + at);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                mimeType: fileType,
                name: fileName,
            }));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                doUpload({
                    location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                    chunks: chunks,
                });
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                console.log(xhr.response);
            };
        }).getAt();
    }

    function doUpload(e) {
        var chunks = e.chunks;
        var location = e.location;
        console.log("this stuff: " + location);
        var cnt = 0;
        var end = chunks.length;
        var temp = function callback(cnt) {
            var e = chunks[cnt];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
            xhr.send(e.data);
            xhr.onloadend = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                cnt += 1;
                console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
                $("#progress").text("Uploading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
                if (status == 308) {
                    callback(cnt);
                    
                } else if (status == 200) {
                    $("#progress").text("Done.");
                } else {
                    $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
                }
            };
        }(cnt);
    }

    function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
        var chunkPot = {};
        chunkPot.total = fileSize;
        chunkPot.chunks = [];
        if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
            var numE = chunkSize;
            var endS = function(f, n) {
                var c = f % n;
                if (c == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return c;
                }
            }(fileSize, numE);
            var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
            for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
                var startAddress = i * numE;
                var c = {};
                c.startByte = startAddress;
                if (i < repeat) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                    c.numByte = numE;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                    c.numByte = endS;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            var chunk = {
                startByte: 0,
                endByte: fileSize - 1,
                numByte: fileSize,
            };
            chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
        }
        return chunkPot;
    }
    



    
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

GS:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html");
}

function getAt() {
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}

// This commented line is used for enabling Drive API and adding a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
// So please don't remove this.
// DriveApp.createFile();
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `I also tried changing the PUT request for the "resuming" but It either errors out with "file not found" if I dont match the original POST or if I do make them the same, It still just uploads to root!`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, if you referred the script from other site or repository, can I ask you about it?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike - in answer to your first question, what Im pretty sure is happening is the first function sets up the upload by doing a XMLHttpRequest.open and uses POST as the method. It uploads a chunk then updates the file with another XMLHttpRequest.open  but this time PUT as the method (as per Google API instructions about 'updating an existing file')

[link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

why dont I ask the person who wrote the code? I simply had too many tabs open and  closed the wrong tab... and now I cant find where I got it :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your script modified the original script and the issue occurs, the reason of the issue might be able to be known by comparing them. So I asked about the source site of the original script. How about this?

Comment: The only thing I changed from the original was the HTML to make it look pretty - And of course, I am using my own Folder ID. The original wasn't trying to pick a folder, it was just intended to get around Google's 50mb limit - So the only thing different is that I am trying to include **addParents=1234....** into my URL in the POST or PUT. The original code had the URL ending directly after: **uploadType=resumable**

Comment: _"If your script modified the original script and the issue occurs"_ 

This is a good point and I see where you are coming from, but really the issue that my changes dont do anything... it just keeps working like the original script and uploading to the root folder. Maybe Im not understanding what Google's API says about **addParents**

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your script in your question is the same with the original script which could be confirmed to work fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As the next step, I would like to confirm your goal and current issue. 1. Your goal is that you want to upload a file to the specific folder on Google Drive with the resumable upload. But, about `this time PUT as the method (as per Google API instructions about 'updating an existing file')`, I cannot understand. How about this? 2. Your issue is that the file is not uploaded to the specific folder. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks again @Tanaike. **1)** There are 2 times in the code the URL is used (once with POST method and once with PUT . I have tried adding the **addParents** parameter to the URL in both. But the File just goes to the root. **2)** Correct, my file is not uploaded to the folder ID that I specify.

**Also**, if it helps I found the Github that I got the code from: [link](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps)

Comment: @Tanaike - Hang on??? am I using your code????  The user on Gitub has the same name!!??  HAHAHA Thats so funny!!!  You are the perfect person to help! Your code is exactly what I was looking for!  Small world!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? And I was surprised that you had used my script. I couldn't notice about it. I'm sorry. I had published a Javascript library for uploading the file using the resumable upload. So I proposed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload a file to the specific folder on Google Drive with the resumable upload.
- You want to achieve this using Javascript by retrieving the access token from Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

- From your replying comment, I could notice that you had used my script. In this case, I had updated the script. In the current stage, I have published a Javascript library for uploading the file with the resumable upload. In this answer, I used this.

### Modified script:

#### HTML and Javascript side (`index.html`):

```
<form><input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file" /></form>
<div id="progress"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js@master/resumableupload_js.min.js"></script>

<script>
  document.getElementById("uploadfile").addEventListener("change", run, false);

  function run(obj) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(accessToken =>
        ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(accessToken, obj)
      )
      .getAuth();
  }

  function ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(accessToken, obj) {
    const file = obj.target.files[0];
    if (file.name != "") {
      let fr = new FileReader();
      fr.fileName = file.name;
      fr.fileSize = file.size;
      fr.fileType = file.type;
      fr.accessToken = accessToken;
      fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      fr.onload = resumableUpload;
    }
  }

  function resumableUpload(e) {
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "Initializing.";
    const f = e.target;
    const resource = {
      fileName: f.fileName,
      fileSize: f.fileSize,
      fileType: f.fileType,
      fileBuffer: f.result,
      accessToken: f.accessToken,
      folderId: "###"  // <--- Please set the folder ID.
    };
    const ru = new ResumableUploadToGoogleDrive();
    ru.Do(resource, function(res, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(res);
      let msg = "";
      if (res.status == "Uploading") {
        msg =
          Math.round(
            (res.progressNumber.current / res.progressNumber.end) * 100
          ) + "%";
      } else {
        msg = res.status;
      }
      document.getElementById("progress").innerText = msg;
    });
  }
</script>
```

- In this case, please set the folder ID to `resource`.

#### Google Apps Script side (`Code.gs`):

```
function getAuth() {
  // DriveApp.createFile(blob) // This is used for adding the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

### Reference:

- [ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js](https://github.com/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js)

### Added:

If you want to modify [your current script](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps), please modify as follows. In the case of the resumable upload, the file metadata is set at the initial request. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

#### From:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    mimeType: fileType,
    name: fileName,
}));
```

#### To:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    mimeType: fileType,
    name: fileName,
    parents: ["###"]  // <--- Please set the folder ID.
}));
```

Comment: 100% Perfect - This is such a good answer! Examples, options, explanations. You are a credit to the Stack Overflow Community!

Comment: @Different Gravity Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.